# How to find the following limit?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

> Can anyone explain how to find that limit?
> $$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\int_0^x \cos \left(t^2\right) \, dt}{x} $$

answer suppose to equal $1$

I tried to solve integral by using the define integral formula and I got $\cos x^2$, however it seems to be wrong, because limit of $\frac{\cos x^2}{x}$ does not exist.

Comment: Please for God's sake do MathJax

Comment: Please try to use Mathjax to format your question. See [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Do you recognize that this is a trivial application of FTC? FTC says this limit is equal to the value of integrand at $t=0$ because the integrand is continuous at $t=0$.

Answer (score 2):

A first and simple way to do it is by observing that : $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}{\cos{\left(y^{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{F\left(x\right)-F\left(0\right)}{x-0}}=F'\left(0\right)=\cos{0}=1 $$

Where $ F $ is the function $ F:x\mapsto\int_{0}^{x}{\cos{\left(y^{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y} $.

Another way to do it would be squeezing, using the inequality $ \left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\right),\ \left|1-\cos{x}\right|\leq\frac{x^{2}}{2} $.

Let $ x\in\mathbb{R}^{*} $, we have :

\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}{\cos{\left(y^{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}=1-\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}{\left(1-\cos{\left(y^{2}\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}y}\end{aligned}

And since : $$ \left|\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}{\left(1-\cos{\left(y^{2}\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}y} \right|\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}{\left|1-\cos{\left(y^{2}\right)}\right|\mathrm{d}y}\leq\frac{1}{2x}\int_{0}^{x}{y^{2}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{x^{2}}{6}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Then : $$ \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}{\cos{\left(y^{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $\;\cos^2 t\;$ , or even $\;\cos t^2\;$  (whatever you meant) is a continuous function, the function $\;g(x):=\int\limits_0^x\cos^2t\,dt\;$ is a differentiable one, and $\;g(0)=0\;$. Thus, you can apply L'Hospital's rule to calculate the limit, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$g'(x)=\cos^2x\; ...$$

whereas the derivative of the denominator is...

Answer (score 0):

$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\int_0^x \cos \left(t^2\right) \, dt}{x}=^*\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_0^x \cos \left(t^2\right) \, dt\right)}{1}=\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\cos x^2=1$$
$*$ applied L'Hopital rule

Comment: Is the square on the cosine or on the variable (last step)?

Comment: @imranfat it's $\cos x^2$. thank you for noting!

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the Maclaurin expansion of $\cos x$ to avoid L’Hôpital’s:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_0^x \left(1-\frac{t^4}{2!} +\dots\right) dt }{x} \\ =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\frac{x^5}{5\cdot 2!} +\dots}{x} \\ =\lim_{x\to 0} 1-\frac{x^4}{5\cdot 2!} +\dots \\ =1$$

Answer (score 0):

MVT for integrals:

$\displaystyle{\int_{0} ^{x}} \cos (t^2) dx=$

$\cos (s^2)\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{x}} dx$ where s \in [0,x];

Note :

$\lim x \rightarrow 0$  implies $\lim t^2 \rightarrow 0.$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \cos (t^2)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

You may just use squeezing. In a right neighbourhood od the origin we have $\cos(z)\leq 1$ and $\cos(z)\geq 1-\frac{z^2}{2}$, since $1-\cos(z)=2\sin^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\leq 2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2$. This leads to $1-\frac{t^4}{2}\leq \cos(t^2)\leq 1$ and to
$$ x-\frac{x^5}{10}\leq \int_{0}^{x}\cos(t^2)\,dt \leq x$$
so the wanted limit is clearly one.

Answer (score 0):

Using L'Hospital rule $$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\Bigg[\frac{\int_0^x \cos \left(t^2\right) \, dt}{x}\Bigg]=\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\Bigg[\frac{\frac d {dx}\int_0^x \cos \left(t^2\right) \, dt}{\frac d {dx}x}\Bigg]=\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\Bigg[\frac d {dx}\int_0^x \cos \left(t^2\right) \, dt\Bigg]$$

Now, using the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\Bigg[\frac d {dx}\int_0^x \cos \left(t^2\right) \, dt\Bigg]=\cos(x^2)$$